# Blogs to follow?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

What's your list of blogs for anything asp.net and vb.net related. I know for instance [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu)'s stuff is the first on the rank for asp.net.

I'm trying to compile a list of 'good' stuff that will teach me things as I read, the more I gather the better, this way I'll get several posts a day, as most blogs post only once a week if that.

---

jsut to list some of my favs, scottgu & phill haack... although he talks too much about his baby!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266085/list-of-net-blogs-worth-following-closed

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551315/which-c-net-blogs-do-you-read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow around **50 different blogs** covering a plethora of different development aspects - including C#, general development tips, and even **[Jeff Atwood's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com)** which is now more about Microsoft Bob than it is `C#`... ;)

You may want to look into using [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com) or [Bloglines](http://www.bloglines.com/) to keep your blogs in check - you'll be notified of any new blog posts and you can easily track older ones also.

My personal favourites would be [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/), [Joel On Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/), [Ayende Rahien](http://ayende.com/Blog/Default.aspx) and [ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could find this list [Top 200 Blogs for Developers (Q3 2009)](http://www.noop.nl/2009/09/top-200-blogs-for-developers-q3-2009.html) useful

Answer (score 0):

I like
[coding horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) and [scott hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/)

and for us Swedes:
[programmeramera](http://programmeramera.se/)